# I am getting this error while installing torch package

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, torch

C:\Users\Utkarsh>pip install torch
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

I am getting the above error!
I have installed python v3.10

I have also tried to install torch from whl file but there also I am getting error like:
[enter image description here][1]
C:\Users\Utkarsh>pip install C:\Users\Utkarsh\Downloads\torch-1.10.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: torch-1.10.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

what should I do?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdzmS.png

Comment: Pytorch does not support Python 3.10 so far.

Comment: So which python version should I Install?

Comment: I think you can go for 3.9

Comment: Does torch package require GPU?

Comment: you hav both the option (cpu and gpu)

Answer (score 1):

ypu need to install `pytorch`

```
pip install pytorch
```

https://pytorch.org/

Comment: That's for conda